# Performance issues with saving object reference to array

Tags: javascript, performance

Why is v1 so much slower than v2?

v1 --

```
var foo = function (a,b,c) { 
   this.a=a; this.b=b; this.c=c; 
}
var pcs = new Array(32);
for (var n=32; n--;) {
    ref = new foo(1,2,3)
    pcs[n] = ref;    //*****
}
```

v2 --

```
var foo = function (a,b,c) { 
   this.a=a; this.b=b; this.c=c; 
}
var pcs = new Array(32);
for (var n=32; n--;) {
    ref = new foo(1,2,3)
    pcs[n] = 1;    //*****
}
```

I figured that since I'm holding a reference to the new object in 'ref', that simply assigning that reference to an element in the array would be about as fast as assigning a literal value, but it turns out that assigning the reference is considerably slower. Can anyone shed some light on this? Anything I can do to improve the performance here on V1?

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/a0kw9rL1/1/

Comment: where loop terminating condition??

Comment: @ozil: Where it always is, the second part of the `for` "header",  `n--`. If it returns `0`, the loop terminates.

Comment: @ Felix Kling what it is not decrements after `0`

Comment: You've basically done your best. If you need to save a reference (which contains more data than a mere number), that's all you can do. On the other hand, ask yourself why you need to improve performances in such a task. Obviously these snippets are proofs of concept, so only you know what's behind.

Comment: How much slower is it?  I don't see a huge difference when trying it on js fiddle.  Would note that you don't declare ref anywhere, so it will be on global scope, in case that is causing you issues.  You're also missing a few semi-colons.

Comment: Yes, sry my code above is a little sloppy. Clearly this is a mockup of what I'm actually doing, but I thought it would be easier to see. ref is local in my code and declared ahead of the for. In Chrome 42 I see V2 being about half the run time with my real code. I'm working on a chess engine so speed is of the utmost.

Comment: Difference for me is negligible. Not enough to determine a literal difference between v1 and v2: http://jsperf.com/array-reference-assignment

Comment: @ozil: I'm not sure what you mean by that. But you can just try it for yourself: `for (var i = 10; i--;) { console.log(i); }`.

Comment: I have tried this and there is a small difference, as you might imagine for allocation of an object, but both still run under a millisecond.  Not sure exactly how much performance you need out of this? http://jsfiddle.net/a0kw9rL1/1/

Comment: Be very careful about [micro benchmarks]( http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html ). It could be the JIT kicking in and optimizing away the object creation completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> simply assigning that reference to an element in the array would be about as fast as assigning a literal value

Yes, it basically is<sup>1</sup>. However, allocating an object probably makes the difference here.
In V2, `ref` is only allocated once and repeatedly overwritten, it might be allocated on the stack not on the heap, and dead code elimination might even completely optimise it away.
In V1, `ref` needs to be allocated on the heap, and repeatedly in a new location, as all the different instances are accessible from `pcs`.

V1 is just eating more memory than V21. However, due to your very small array, the difference is neglible. If you use really large one, you can spot the difference: http://jsperf.com/array-reference-assignment/3

<sub>[1]: Well, for some reason [not really](http://jsperf.com/array-reference-assignment/5). But I can't explain that, except garbage collection is different when you profile memory usage</sub>

Comment: I think this is the right answer except 'V1' and 'V2' are reversed in it's current version.  Possibly making that update (if you agree with me) would get this accepted.

Comment: @Bergi _"it might be allocated on the stack not on the heap"_ Can describe "stack" , "heap" ; differences between the two ? , for a viewer that may not have a lay reference point for those terms within computer science ?

Comment: @guest271314: [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) vs [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#Dynamic_memory_allocation).

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the performance difference reported by the OP?  One of the comments posted a link showing no perf difference (http://jsperf.com/array-reference-assignment) and I noticed the same thing running with the console.  I'm wondering how the OP saw a performance difference between the two versions in the first place.

Comment: @GabrielSouthern: Yes, see the jsperf links in my answers, that are based on RGrahams version. However, indeed the differences are neglible for the size-32-arrays.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the explanation.  I still don't see how the OP noticed a performance difference in the code posted in the question, but your example shows how there could be a performance different and maybe the code in the question is a simplified example from something the OP saw that does have a performance difference.

Comment: @Bergi - great answer, your code here http://jsperf.com/array-reference-assignment/3 is a much better example that illustrates the difference between the two versions. I'm sorry my code above wasn't very useful. During my own testing, w/ the actual code, the difference was clearly apparent, so I must be doing something fundamentally different. The following test more closely represents my original tests which shows the performance difference clearly. I think the 100k loop puts a lot more emphasis on the ref, proportionally, to the rest of the ops. http://jsperf.com/array-reference-assignment/9

Comment: It occurs to me that in my example, I am still using a small array, unlike in revision 3. Why do you think my latest revision #11 shows such a performance difference still. Is it because the reference is emphasized with the 100k loop, making it proportionally more of the operations?